# How to show validation message below each textbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a login form in which I have email address and password as the textbox. I have done the validation on the email address part so that it should have proper email address and also on the empty check both for email address and password text box.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoksoh69/5/).

As of now, I have added an alert box saying, `Invalid` if email address and password textbox is empty. Instead of that, I would like to show a simple message just below each text box saying , please enter your email address or password if they are empty?

Just like it has been done here on [sitepoint blog](https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/).

Is this possible to do in my current HTML form?

**Update:-**

```
<body>

    <div id="login">

        <h2>
            <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>Sign In
        </h2>

        <form action="login" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">E-mail address</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
                </p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
    <!-- end login -->

</body>
```

And my JS -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!$('#email').val()) {
                if ($("#email").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
                {
                    $("#email").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter email address</div>");
                }
            } else {
                $("#email").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            if (!$('#password').val()) {
                if ($("#password").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
                {
                    $("#password").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter password</div>");

                }
            } else {
                $("#password").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

I am working with JSP and Servlets so as soon as I click Sign In button, it was taking me to another page with valid email and password earlier but now nothing is happening after I click Sign In button with valid email and password.

Any thoughts what could be wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could put static elements after the fields and show them, or you could inject the validation message dynamically. See the below example for how to inject dynamically.

This example also follows the best practice of setting focus to the blank field so user can easily correct the issue.

Note that you could easily genericize this to work with any label & field (for required fields anyway), instead of my example which specifically codes each validation.

Your fiddle is updated, see here: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aoksoh69/17/)

The code:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var focusSet = false;
    if (!$('#email').val()) {
        if ($("#email").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
        {
            $("#email").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter email address</div>");
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
        $('#email').focus();
        focusSet = true;
    } else {
        $("#email").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
    }
    if (!$('#password').val()) {
        if ($("#password").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
        {
            $("#password").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter password</div>");
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
        if (!focusSet) {
            $("#password").focus();
        }
    } else {
        $("#password").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
    }
});
```

The CSS:

```
    .validation
    {
      color: red;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for not using append as append has the potential of adding more and more elements in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, but so does `after`, although it would insert them before the last validation messsage. I addressed this by checking `.length == 0` before using `.after()`

Comment: @nothingisnecessary This  works fine for validation. But as soon as I click `Sign In` button after having valid email and password, it is not taking me to another page, it just get stuck on the same page as nothing happened after  clicking Sign In button with valid email and password. I have updated the question with the way I am using it. Earlier, it used to take me to right page after pressing Sign In button with valid email and password. See my action tag in the form which I am using with servlets.

Comment: Move this line into each section that adds the validation error: `e.preventDefault()` and it should allow you to POST the form to server. I updated my example to show this.

Comment: "best practice of setting focus" - this was before I did much with mobile web. With mobile web setting focus can be annoying because may bring up the device's OSK and block user's view. oh, how we learn

Comment: **Nice solution** for displaying HTML elements' validation error messages. However I could not get this to work for table `td` elements. It keeps pushing the next `td` (**cell**) away (towards the right) to accommodate the error message.

Comment: Got this to work by removing `.parent()` and only using `.after()`. Now the error message is placed exactly under the table **cell**.

Comment: @12379095 Glad you got it working. It was tightly coupled to the HTML structure which is not good practice, as you found. Another way would be using classes and `.closest()` to find the nearest matching parent, like this: `$("#id").closest(".field-container").after()` etc., for tables this could be `$("#id").closest("table")` to find parent table of an element in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

is only the matter of finding the dom where you want to insert the the text.

DEMO [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aoksoh69/8/)

```
$().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to create paragraph tags where you want your error messages with the same class and show them when the data is invalid. Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoksoh69/9/)

```
if ($('#email').val() == '' || !$('#password').val() == '') {
    $('.loginError').show();
    return false;
}
```

I also added the paragraph tags below the email and password inputs

```
<p class="loginError" style="display:none;">please enter your email address or password.</p>
```

Comment: Generally I agree with your approach for login forms, but OP asked: "I would like to show a simple message just below each text box," not a single message for all fields.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I read it as he want the same message regardless if both are empty or if one has input. Generally I do separate error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (!$('#email').val()) 
        $('#email').parent().append('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
    
    
    if(!$('#password').val())
         $('#password').parent().append('<span class="error">Please enter your password.</span>');
});
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- FONTAWESOME ---------- */
/* ---------- http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ ---------- */
/* ---------- http://weloveiconfonts.com/ ---------- */

@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

/* ---------- ERIC MEYER'S RESET CSS ---------- */
/* ---------- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ---------- */

@import url(http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css);

/* ---------- FONTAWESOME ---------- */

[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

body {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Varela Round", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

input {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* ---------- LOGIN ---------- */

#login {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 400px;
}

#login h2 {
    background-color: #f95252;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px 26px;
}

#login h2 span[class*="fontawesome-"] {
    margin-right: 14px;
}

#login fieldset {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px 26px;
}

#login fieldset div {
    color: #777;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#login fieldset p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#login fieldset input {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#login fieldset .error {
    display: block;
     color: #FF1000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
}

#login fieldset input[type="email"], #login fieldset input[type="password"] {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #777;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 328px;
}

#login fieldset input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #33cc77;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px 0;
    width: 100px;
}

#login fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #28ad63;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login">

<h2><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>Sign In</h2>

<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">

    <fieldset>

        <div><label for="email">E-mail address</label></div>
        <div><input type="email" id="email" /></div>

        <div><label for="password">Password</label></div>
        <div><input type="password" id="password" /></div> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Email" -->

        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></div>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

And the fiddle: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xL91ggk8/1/)

Comment: -1 because your solution keeps adding validation labels instead of checking if already present (on the fiddle, click the button multiple times in a row)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple solution may work for you.

[Check this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/hamix/nw28pkp7/1/)

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var emailBox=$("#email");
var passBox=$("#password");
if (!emailBox.val() || !passBox.val()) {
    $(".validationText").text("Please Enter Value").show();
}
else if(!IsEmail(emailBox.val()))
{
    emailBox.prev().text("Invalid E-mail").show();
}
$("input#email, input#password").focus(function(){
    $(this).prev(".validationText").hide();
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

**We will use the jQuery Validation Plugin**

> we have to include the necessary files in our project. There are two different files to include. The first is the core file, which includes the core features of the plugin, including everything from different validation methods to some custom selectors. The second file contains additional methods to validate inputs like credit card numbers and US-based phone numbers.

> You can add these files to your projects via package managers like Bower or NPM.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
   <form id="basic-form" action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name <span>(required, at least 3 characters)</span></label>
      <input id="name" name="name" minlength="3" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">E-Mail <span>(required)</span></label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </p>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
   body {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  width: 300px;
}

form, p {
  margin: 20px;
}

p.note {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: red;
}

input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

label {
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

label span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

label.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

input.error {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: red;
}

[type="submit"], [type="reset"], button, html [type="button"] {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

**Java script**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#basic-form").validate();
});
```

> This is based on the assumption that you have already added the required JavaScript files. Adding those lines of JavaScript will make sure that your form is properly validated and shows all the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

2023 answer: I took Dilip Kumar Choudhary's answer and cut it down with new CSS rules.

**CSS:**

```
label:has(input[required]) span.LabelTxt:first-child::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
span.ErrMsgTxt{visibility:hidden;color: red;font-size:smaller;}
input:user-invalid ~ span.ErrMsgTxt{visibility:visible;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="CheckFormValidity()">
<label>
    <span class="LabelTxt">Name</span>
    <input name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}" type="text" required>
    <span class="ErrMsgTxt">Name must be at least three characters long</span>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <span class="LabelTxt">E-Mail</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    <span class="ErrMsgTxt">Valid e-mail required</span>
</label>
<br>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
CheckFormValidity(targetedForm=event.target){
    if (!targetedForm.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault();return;
    }
}
```