# How to recreate an element by giving css property through inputs in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i had created a layout in which i have a form with multiple inputs  and a block element (Div) which has already created. Now i want give value (as in px) in input fields  and block should be recreated for e.g if the block has 30px width and 30px height initially now i want to change it through inputs  when i submit the form the block should be recreated. i think this is to be done in javascript or jquery. Please help me out of this situation your will will be appericiated. here is code below

This is the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gr0q5ea0/

Html

```
    <div class="form-container">
        <form action="" id="myForm" name="myForm">
            <div class="recreateBox"></div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="leftSetction">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Height:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-input inputbox" name="height">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftSetction">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Width:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-input inputbox" name="width">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="leftSetction">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Border Width:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-input inputbox" name="Borderwidth">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="leftSetction">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Border Radius:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-input inputbox" name="Borderradius">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="input-container">
                    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit" >Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

css

```
.form-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(40, 91, 255, 0.24);
    margin: auto auto 35px auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    top: 17px;
}
.input-container{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.form-label{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    color:#000;
}
.form-input{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-row{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btnSubmit{
    padding: 10px 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: #31708f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: white;
    border:none;

}

.leftSetction ,.rightSection{
    width: 49%;
    padding-top: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.inputbox{
    width: 100%;
}
.recreateBox{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #5cb85c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery to solve it. Whenever the form is submitted just give the box a new CSS-attribute:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // Hook onto the form's submittion-event
    $('#myForm').submit( function( event ) {

        // Cancel the original submitting-event
        event.preventDefault();

        // Retrieve the values from the inputfields
        var height = $('#myForm input[name="height"]').val();
        var width = $('#myForm input[name="width"]').val();
        var borderWidth = $('#myForm input[name="Borderwidth"]').val();
        var borderRadius = $('#myForm input[name="Borderradius"]').val();

        // Retrieve field (best practice for jQuery)
        $recreateBox = $('.recreateBox');

        // Set CSS-attributes of the box
        $recreateBox.css('height', height);
        $recreateBox.css('width', width);
        $recreateBox.css('border-width', borderWidth);
        $recreateBox.css('border-radius', borderRadius + 'px');

    });
</script>
```

Just copy & paste this at the bottom of your file.

*Updated JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/gr0q5ea0/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/gr0q5ea0/5/_)*

Best of luck!

Comment: can you please update the Fiddle With this code that will be your most kindness

Comment: @Mujtaba Hussain Bhat, you need to add a "px" to the value in order to work.

Comment: @ TV why should only for border radius  why not others.. i am not getting this... but its works ... Thank u soooooooooooooo much.... i have another question can you please help in that... this this url   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470056/validation-for-inputs-in-jquery-using-regex

Comment: @TheodoreK. Oh thanks! Edited that. https://jsfiddle.net/gr0q5ea0/5/ Totally forgot about it, thank you for pointing it out Theodore.

Comment: @ TheodoreK . i have another question can you please help in that... this is the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470056/validation-for-inputs-in-jquery-using-regex

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can solve it like this (demo here https://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/rmOyEN)

```
$('.btnSubmit').click(function(){
  //Get the given values
  var h = $('input[name=height]').val();
  var w = $('input[name=width]').val();
  var bw = $('input[name=Borderwidth]').val();
  var br = $('input[name=Borderradius]').val();

  //Set the values
  $('.recreateBox').css('height',h);
  $('.recreateBox').css('width',w);
  $('.recreateBox').css('border-width',bw);
  $('.recreateBox').css('border-radius',br+'px');//Needs that 'px' to work
});
```

There's no need to use form submit for this, so I also changed the button type from `submit` to `button`

Comment: @ TheodoreK . i have another question can you please help in that... this is the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470056/validation-for-inputs-in-jquery-using-regex

Answer (score 0):

Take value for input height and width and use jquery for modifying the width and height of the box.

```
var height= $("input[name=height]").val();
$(".recreateBox").css("height", height);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know this can be done through jquery what you have tried ?

you can get the value of the input boxes using class selector something like this -

var a = $('.input').val()

and then use that value to set the css od that div -

$(".yourDiv").css({"height": a });

you can do all this on the click event of the button.