# form error based on data-attribute value or using jquery with data-attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

```
<form _ngcontent-c10="" action="" id="sign-in" method="post" novalidate="" data-context="sign-in" class="ng-invalid">

 <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="row">
 <label _ngcontent-c10="" for="username">Username</label>
 <input _ngcontent-c10="" id="username" name="username" required="" type="text" value="" class="ng-untouched">
 <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="error" data-sign-in-error="username error">
              **field balnk**
 </div>
</div>

<div _ngcontent-c10="" class="row">
 <label _ngcontent-c10="" for="password">Password</label>
 <input _ngcontent-c10="" id="password" minlength="6" name="password" required="" type="password" value="" class="ng-invalid">
 <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="alert-error">
  <div _ngcontent-c10="" data-sign-in-error"="password-error">
             **password insufficient length**
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Whenever data-sign-in-error is visible I want to print the input id with the corresponding div data attribute value. The output should be 
username-username error, password-password-error 
I don't want to use classes as a selector.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far yourself

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572882/how-to-show-validation-message-below-each-textbox-using-jquery) you mean?

Comment: $('[data-aa-app-sign-in-form-error]').each(function() {
    var triggerValue = $(this).attr("data-aa-app-sign-in-form-error");
console.log($(this).parent().find(':input').attr('id')+' '+triggerValue);

});   


output : username username-error
undefined password-error

Comment: undefined should be replaced with password and output should look like password password error