# Simple Login form with HTML,CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to build a simple login form with HTML and CSS and I am using Javascript for empty field validations.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuwd0Lzo/6/)

I am trying to validate for empty text on the textboxes and display the error message below each textbox using the css and HTML.

CSS

```
.validation
{
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#txtUsername").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter username</div>");
```

I am trying to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572882/how-to-show-validation-message-below-each-textbox-using-jquery) and replicate same but somehow it it not working.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What functionality are you trying to replicate and which part doesn't work?

Comment: Define "not working". What errors do you get? Please post a [mcve] in your question and properly tag it (it appears as if you're using jQuery but the tag is missing)

Comment: Not working the validation.If you would have opened jsfiddle, I am sure you noticed it.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, jQuery is not added as a library. Thus your jQuery validation code is not being called.

[image]

It works if you add jQuery.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this..Thanks much

Comment: @Santosh You're welcome! Please make sure to mark this answer as accepted to show the community it helped you.